# Problem in reading Mapbox vector tile pbf using OGR

Tags: mapbox, geojson, vector-tiles

I want to convert pbf vector tiles created in Geoserver to GeoJson format. For that I've used this [link](https://www.gdal.org/drv_mvt.html) which gives not much instruction on how to do it. I've tested with `ogrinfo 6449_traffic.vector.pbf` in Linux terminal which gives me the following error:

```
Unable to open datasource `6449_traffic.vector.pbf' with the following drivers.
  -> PCIDSK
  -> netCDF
  -> JP2OpenJPEG
  -> PDF
  -> ESRI Shapefile
  -> MapInfo File
  -> UK .NTF
  -> OGR_SDTS
  -> S57
  -> DGN
  -> OGR_VRT
  -> REC
  -> Memory
  -> BNA
  -> CSV
  -> NAS
  -> GML
  -> GPX
  -> LIBKML
  -> KML
  -> GeoJSON
  -> Interlis 1
  -> Interlis 2
  -> OGR_GMT
  -> GPKG
  -> SQLite
  -> OGR_DODS
  -> ODBC
  -> WAsP
  -> PGeo
  -> MSSQLSpatial
  -> OGR_OGDI
  -> PostgreSQL
  -> MySQL
  -> OpenFileGDB
  -> XPlane
  -> DXF
  -> CAD
  -> Geoconcept
  -> GeoRSS
  -> GPSTrackMaker
  -> VFK
```

How can I convert mvt.pbf file to GeoJson using this tool or any alternative ones?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and this https://github.com/mapbox/pbf worked for me. You need 2 files:

- The schema file (usually a `.proto` file)
- The data file (your `.pbf` file)

First you need to convert the `.proto` into a `.js` with: `pbf Schema.proto > Schema.js`

Then you can Read or Write the pbf, for this you need to execute some javascript and html code and launch from the web browser. Or, If you want to launch from terminal, use `node`, on this way (**data_extractor.js**):

```
// Imports
var fs = require("fs");
var Pbf = require('pbf');
var Vector_Tile = require('./Schema.js').Tile;
// *Tile* is the exported object of my schema file. You need to check what is yours.

// Read the .pbf
var pbf = new Pbf(fs.readFileSync('./ogrinfo 6449_traffic.vector.pbf'));
var obj = Vector_Tile.read(pbf);
console.log(obj)
```

- then run on a terminal: `node data_extractor.js`